# MS Access: How to specify a ODBC Connection String with country specific date queries?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, localization, odbc

I have severe troubles to set up an MS access application that uses linked tables to an SQL Server 2012 Database.

The problem is that SQL Queries have problems to interpret German dates: e.g. "31.12.2019" doesn't work, "01.01.2019" works. So I suspect that it is a problem with localization. E.g.

```
select * from table where date >= [Forms]![someForm]![fromDate]
```

*[Forms]![someForm]![fromDate]* is a string in a form, edited by a date picker.

I was able to solve the problem by using the ODBC Microsoft SQL Server Setup Wizzard, and selecting "Ländereinstellungen verwenden" (engl. use country specific settings).

(Sorry the following screenshot is in German).

[image: ODBC Connection via wizzard]

I would like to specify this in a classic ODBC connection string: e.g

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=.\SqlExpress2012;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=suplattform;?country-specific=yes?
```

However I did not find such an parameter in any documentation. Is this possible?

Best regards

Michael

Comment: did you try `DataValue(formDateFiled)`  ?

Comment: I believe that the connection string attribute you're looking for is `;Regional=Yes`

Comment: @Gord Thompson : Thank you, that was just what I was looking for. Finally I also found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15 after knowing what to search for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also, specify the *data type* of the parameter - and *date* is a reserved word in Access SQL:

```sql
parameters [Forms]![someForm]![fromDate] DateTime;
select * from table where [date] >= [Forms]![someForm]![fromDate]
```